# How to call a PL/SQL procedure with %ROWTYPE and RECORD as OUT parameters in Java?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, callable-statement

PROCEDURE has 2 OUT parameters, that CallableStatement wants registered.
One is of RECORD TYPE, this is the OUT value that actually interests me.

```
create PACKAGE         my_package IS

  TYPE my_rec_type IS RECORD
  ( field1                                 VARCHAR2(40 CHAR)  DEFAULT '0'
  , field2                                 VARCHAR2(240 CHAR)
  , field3                                 VARCHAR2(1 CHAR)  DEFAULT '1'
    );
END my_package;
```

The other one is of %ROWTYPE.

The procedure itself looks like this:

```
PROCEDURE myProcedure(p_my_tbl1_rec          IN     schema2.my_table1%ROWTYPE
                    , p_my_tbl2_rec          IN     schema2.my_table2%ROWTYPE
               
                    , p_to_my_table1_rec     OUT    schema2.my_table1%ROWTYPE
                    , p_my_rec               OUT    schema2.my_package.my_rec_type)
  BEGIN 
      ...
  END myProcedure;
```

Is used a workaround to map my Java objects to %ROWTYPE inputs that the Oracle procedure can use.

```
Connection con = dataSource.getConnection();

        String sql = """
                declare p_my_tbl1_rec      schema2.my_table1%ROWTYPE; 
                        p_my_tbl2_rec      schema2.my_table2%ROWTYPE;
                        
                        p_to_my_table1_rec schema2.my_table1%ROWTYPE;
                        p_my_rec           schema2.my_package.my_rec_type;
                        
                begin 
                    p_my_tbl1_rec.TABLE_FIELD1                  :=  :table1TableField1;
                    p_my_tbl1_rec.TABLE_FIELD2                  :=  :table1TableField2;
                    ...
                    p_my_tbl2_rec.TABLE_FIELD1                  :=  :table2TableField1; 
                    p_my_tbl2_rec.TABLE_FIELD2                  :=  :table2TableField2;
                    ...
                    
                    p_to_my_table1_rec                       :=  ???
                    p_my_rec                                 :=  ???
                    
                    myProcedure( p_my_tbl1_rec         => p_my_tbl1_rec
                               , p_my_tbl2_rec         => p_my_tbl2_rec
                        
                               , p_to_my_table1_rec    => p_to_my_table1_rec
                               , p_my_rec              => p_my_rec);
                end;
                """;
        CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall(sql);
        // This is how I can map a Java object to %ROWTYPE TYPE
        cs.setLong  ("table1TableField1", myObject1.getTable1TableField1());
        cs.setString("table1TableField2", myObject1.getTable1TableField2());
        ...
        cs.setLong  ("table2TableField1", myObject2.getTable2TableField1());
        cs.setString("table2TableField2", myObject2.getTable2TableField2());
        ...

        cs.registerOutParameter("p_to_my_table1_rec", ???);
        cs.registerOutParameter("p_my_rec", ???);
        cs.execute();
```

**Expectation:**
I call the procedure, I can verify the database, that the procedure has indeed been called. Ideally I can map p_my_rec to a Java object, for future use.

**Reality:**
i have tried different things. STRUCT seems to be the thing I am loking for, but I do not know how to define it correctly. Sometimes, when I tried calling
`cs.registerOutParameter("schema2.my_package.my_rec_type", STRUCT);`
it did not find schema2.my_package.my_rec_type. Could it be, because it is in a PACKAGE?
If you can help me I would be very grateful. Also, if you can provide me an alternative way to call procedures with %ROWTYPE parameter values, that would also help a lot.

Comment: Should be a SCHEMA-level object (CREATE TYPE ... AS OBJECT), not any PL/SQL data type (RECORD, etc.)

Comment: Package-defined types should work just fine in PL/SQL like this. Just ensure you have exec privs on the package. To actually populate it, you need to use the type name as a constructor: ` p_my_rec := schema2.my_package.my_rec_type(:field1,:field2,:field3);`

Comment: As for the %ROWTYPE parameters, I think you have the right idea: structure using a wrapping PL/SQL block which assigns the elements of the record individually, just like you're doing. %ROWTYPE is really intended for intra-PL/SQL easy of typing and internal passing of records, not interaction with clients outside the database.

Comment: If you need to destructure for OUT, then simply refer to the elements by name: `:field1 := p_my_rec.field1;  :field2 := p_my_rec.field2`, and the same for the ROWTYPE records.